# how do you get the maximum per key for an Array [(Int,Double)] and then aggregate them

Tags: arrays, scala

how do we the most efficient way to getting the maximum values for an Array[(Int,Double)] and then aggregate it to get sum

example:

```
  Array[(Int, Double)] = Array((0,2.0), (1,1.0), (1,1.0), (2,2.0), (2,1.0))
```

aggregate: 7

result

```
    Array[(Int, Double)] = Array((0,2.0), (1,1.0), (2,2.0))
```

aggregate : 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient, but it is succinct:

```
val xs = Array((0,2.0), (1,1.0), (1,1.0), (2,2.0), (2,1.0))
val maxs = xs.groupBy(_._1).values.map{_.maxBy(_._2)}
//> maxs  : Iterable[(Int, Double)] = List((2,2.0), (1,1.0), (0,2.0))
val aggregate = maxs.map(_._2).sum
//> aggregate  : Double = 5.0
```